# Google Sites gadgets, extra scroll bars, footer menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Does anybody know how to change a google sites gadget so it has 100% width and 100% height so that there aren't two scroll bars on a single page?  Basically, I want the entire page to just be this one gadget, I don't mind if I have to have the footer menu google inserts into all it's sites pages, but I would like to permanently fix that footer to the bottom 5% or so of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height of the gadget to "100%"?

Comment: yup, it's still got like a 5 to 10% border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't eliminate the left and right margins, but you can minimize them by choosing a template that doesn't have a very wide side margins, like the "Ember" theme.

- Go into **MANAGE SITE**; at the bottom of the list,
- choose "**Themes, Colors, and Fonts**",
- and change the **BASE THEME** TO "**Ember**".

That theme has a fairly thin left and right margin.

Use an HTML App in an Apps Script Gadget for your HTML content.  The only way to avoid the second scroll bar, is to make sure that the height of the gadget is always taller than your App will be.  Set it to something like 1000px.

[image: Gadget Height]

Setting the Gadget Height to something like 1000px, will probably push the Google footer off the bottom of most computer screens.  So, even though the Google Footer is still there, it will be off the bottom of the screen.

If your HTML doesn't fill the height of the Gadget box, there could be white space at the bottom of the screen.  So, just make sure your HTML has enough height to fill the height of the computer screen.

If you have your own footer in the HTML, people may never scroll down lower in the page to see the white space, or the Google Footer.  And you can fill some of the white space with a DIV with no content, but some background color:

```
<div style="background: brown">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Put that after your own Footer.  Just make sure that the gadget height is quite big to avoid the scroll bar on the left.

Answer (score 0):

## Page content width

1. Click on Settings > Edit site layout
2. Set the site width to 100%

[image: Edit site layout options]

## Page content height

Google Sites gadgets aren't not responsive, so you should set a height large enough to avoid vertical scroll bars. If yo will have blank space, match it's background to the site background.